# Using a jQuery tooltip plugin to display Custom Taxonomy descriptions

Tags: custom-taxonomy, jquery

I have a Custom Taxonomy called `groups` as part of my `species` Custom Post Type.

On the front-end of my website, each parent Group displays in a box, with a title and a description.

The children of said parent Group then display as single line `<li>`.

[image: How the groups are displayed on the front-end of the website]

I would like to use a JavaScript plugin to display the description of each of these children when a user hovers over the link. For example, hover over "*Hatchetfishes*" and see the description for that Group, which might be "*All fishes from the genera Gasteropelecidae*".

I've had a look at [ClueTip](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/) and I like the styling/simplicity of the plugin, so if possible, I'd quite like to use that. I'm totally open to using others though, as long as they're based on jQuery and are lightweight.

What would be the most efficient way of doing this? I have 7 parent Groups and 39 children on one page; no descriptions are longer than 20 words.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: This one's clear off-topic and would better fit on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the `<li>` that holds the children, put the description of the children. Default behavior for these should be to not display, and they should presumably all have the same class.  You can then set another class (or just apply css directly with jQuery) to make these display.